# How can make user-defined-function with ADO connection

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ado, user-defined-functions

Please help me create a user defined function in excel vba
example

```
Function GetTheValue(wbPath, wbName, wsName, cellRef)
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim tmp As Range
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
      "Data Source=" & wbPath & wbName & ";" & _
      "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"""
    rst.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & wsName & "$" & cellRef & "]", cnn
    Set tmp = Range("L5")
    tmp.CopyFromRecordset rst
    MsgBox tmp.Value
    GetTheValue = tmp.Value
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
End Function
```

I tryed to use this in cell by signing formula

```
=GetThaValue("D:\";"test.xls";"Sheet1";"B4")
```

and see that the string "tmp.CopyFromRecordset rst" of my code did not work
Please can you help me resolve this question.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call this function from any excel cell there are some changes required.

**First-** I made some test and it seems to be not allowed to point single cell in SQL statement, therefore it will be required to call your function in this way:

```
=GetThaValue("D:\";"test.xls";"Sheet1";"B4:B5")
```

where first cell `B4` will be one you search.

**Second-** The function slightly improved with some comments inside looks as follows:

```
Function GetTheValue(wbPath, wbName, wsName, cellRef)
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim tmp As Range
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

    'some changes here according to www.ConnectionStrings.Com
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & wbPath & wbName & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;"""

    rst.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & wsName & "$" & cellRef & "]", cnn

    'Set tmp = Range("L5")      'NOT needed here
    'tmp.CopyFromRecordset rst   'NOT allowed if function is called from Excel
    'MsgBox tmp.Value           'NOT necessary in this function

    'NEW- in this way we get value of your cell and pass it to excel
    GetTheValue = rst.Fields(0).Value

    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
End Function
```

I can confirm it's tested for Excel 2010 and it's working fine.

Comment: you possibly need to return to your original connection string which I've changed based on ConnectionStrings.Com.